# Powering 3.3V I2C from Arduino 5V?

Tags: voltage-regulator, i2c, level-shifting, 5v, 3.3v

I need my Arduino to communicate with a fairly sensitive 3.3V I2C device, and am using a [Bidirectional Level Converter](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12009) to step down the voltage.

However, I still need a 3.3V source (for the I2C device and Level Converter), and the Arduino shield I am using is blocking the 3.3V pin.

**My question to you all:** what is the best (easiest/cheapest/most efficient) way to get 3.3V to that I2C device?

**My options as I see them:** make a voltage divider from the 5V (pictured), buy a $1 voltage regulator, or do solder-surgery on the ardu-shield so I can use it.

**Edit:** I should clarify this is NOT a small stationary project. The choice needs to be durable and repeatable/manufacturable.

Option 1 (looks super inefficient):

[image: Logic Converter circuit]

Comment: I2C level shifting won't work like that. Do some searching about 5V to/from 3.3V I2C level shifting; plenty has been written about it.

Comment: Well that's funny, I've been successfully communicating using that bi-directional level converter the whole time [exactly like this](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/bi-directional-logic-level-converter-hookup-guide). So clearly one of us misunderstands the other.

Comment: I completely misread the question and thought it was about signal shifting, not supply generation. Woops.

Comment: I'd still vote for soldering a piece of wire to solve your problem.. seems more straightforward than to order a regulator and building something to add it to your circuit.

Comment: The question then becomes "how can I solder a wire to a small joint multiple times so that it is rugged and repeatable?"

Comment: @GraemeRock - re-design the shield to be what you need and incorporate the level shifting.  Or re-design the Arduino to do so, or modify it to run on 3.3v.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a voltage divider to generate a power rail is most often a bad idea, as you don't know what your current draw is, and you don't know if it will be a constant current draw.  Think about how inaccurate your divider will be with a circuit sucking 20 milliamps from it.  It's a calculation worth doing.

This is what voltage regulators are for.  Try http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Microchip/MCP1702-3302E-TO/?qs=jZi1jxfVU95RAHKJCz8stQ%3D%3D&gclid=CMyooOLjss4CFdcZgQodzxQCBw  for a 50 cent part  -  but you need to verify that it can deal with enough current for your purposes.

As to whether it's worth your time to dork around with your board/shield, thats up to you.

Comment: Verified: This voltage regulator provides 250mA, and the I2C device draws absolute maximum 5-8 mA per pin. I think the Level Converter should be fine too then.

Comment: @GraemeRock  -- great.  Pore over the data sheet a bit more.  Sometimes devices like this want to operate under a bit of a constant load, in which case you would add a resistor in parallel to your circuit

Comment: I do not exactly understand what you mean - Which data sheet are your referring to? I have three in front of me. Do you mean I might want to add a resistor in parallel with the I2C device between 3.3V and GND? Or with the voltage regulator? Or between 5V and GND?

Comment: @GraemeRock  the data sheet for the LDO, http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/268/22008a-53656.pdf.  Peeking now, I don't see the need for a resistor.  You will certainly need the capacitors indicated in the data sheet

Comment: Oh geez, I completely missed that! Thanks for letting me know. I just added those!